# Do frequencies of digit occurences on PI ever become even?

Tags: pi

I found this link about frequencies of digits appearing in π : 
http://www.eveandersson.com/pi/precalculated-frequencies

This made me wonder: do those frequencies ever become even on the lifespan of the currently known digits? (each of the 10 digits [0,1,...,9] appearing n times on the (10*n)'th digit)

If not, what's the closest they get to, and when?

Comment: The word "even" is a little unclear. Do you mean "after some point only the digits $0, 2, 4, 6, 8$ occur"?  Or do you mean "the frequencies of each digit become (nearly) the same"?  Neither is known but it speculated that $\pi$ is a normal number.  Search for "normal number".

Comment: Sorry about that. I expected the context to have made it clear enough. I meant each of the 10 digits appearing n times on the (10n)'th digit.

Comment: i just wanted to be sure.  As I said, it is speculated but not proven that $\pi$ is normal.  So, I suggest reading up on that.  However, it is not proven.  It could be that after a certain point, the digit $9$ never appears.

Answer (score 2):

It's unlikely.  If you take $10n$ random decimal digits, the probability that you have $n$ each of $0, 1, \ldots, 9$ is $(10 n)! 10^{-10n}/(n!)^{10}$.  In an infinite sequence of random digits, the expected number of positive integers $n$ for which this is true is
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(10 n)! 10^{-10n}}{(n!)^{10}} \approx 0.0003933209904$$
most of which ($0.00036288$) comes from the $n=1$ term.

Of course the digits of $\pi$ are not really random, but their statistical properties are (as far as we can tell) similar to a random sequence, and in this case we know that the first $10$ digits are not evenly distributed (e.g. digits $2$ and $4$ are both $1$).